# Empty page and this.state.postLists.map is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

after I added this code I got blank page, nothing is loading. I guess that there is something wrong in **componentWillReceiveProps** but I don't know what exactly.

Also I have "Uncaught TypeError: this.state.postLists.map is not a function" in the console

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { getDocs, collection, deleteDoc, doc } from "firebase/firestore";
import { auth, db } from '../firebaseconf';

class Home extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            postLists: ''
        }
    }

    setPostList = (newValue) => {
        this.setState({
            postLists: newValue
        });
    }

    postsCollectionRef = collection(db, "posts");

    componentWillReceiveProps = (nextProps) => {
        if (nextProps.position !== this.props.position) {
            const getPosts = async () => {
                const data = await getDocs(this.postsCollectionRef);
                this.setPostList(data.docs.map((doc) => ({ ...doc.data(), id: doc.id })));
            };

            getPosts();
        }
    }

    deletePost = async (id) => {
        const postDoc = doc(db, "posts", id);
        await deleteDoc(postDoc);
    };



    render() {
        return (
            <div className="homePage">
                {this.state.postLists.map((post) => {
                    return (
                        <div className="post"> {post.title} </div>
                    );
                })}

            </div>
        );
    }
}
export default Home;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set initial value of postLists in state as array

```
this.state = {
     postLists: []
}
```

And maybe its also good idea to add some ternary operator if there is no data something like:

```
{this.state.postLists.length ?  this.state.postLists.map((post) => {
      return (
       <div className="post"> {post.title} </div>
      );
}) : 'No data'}
```

Also think about replacing `componentWillReceiveProps` with `componentDidUpdate` because `componentDidUpdate` should now be used rather than `componentWillReceiveProps`

From React docs: https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html

Comment: ok, thanks, i did that changes but now it always show me "No data", i changed it to componentDidUPdate and deleted line below with if statement it looks to me like setPostLists isnt updating state, do u know whats im doing wrong now?

Comment: can you show me your componentDidUpdate?

Answer (score 1):

The root cause of your issue is here:

```
this.state = {
            postLists: ''
        }
```

You are defining postLists as a string, and using the array .map() method which is causing the error.